# Displaying score view in another XML

Tags: java, android, xml

So my main error is in the ScoreDisplay.java

public class ScoreDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score;

```
score= getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
```

}

int score is fine but in the next line it says 
- unknown class score
-invalid method declaration; return type required
- missing method body, or declare abstract
- parameter expected

and yea so everything is red in my java class and where do i put my textview.textview show ect. that you told me?

Comment: My final xml is called scoredisplay.xml

Comment: If you go to the bottom of my QuizActivity.java, then youll see;                    public void endingScore (View view) {
        mfinalScoreView = mScore;

Comment: Thats the place where i need help, what code should go there to update the value 0 in my final xml layout?

Comment: MultipleQA/app/src/main/res/layout/scoredisplay.xml

Comment: where your `scoredisplay.java` ?

Comment: What do you mean,

Comment: The scoredisplay.java is in the bottom of my main java

Comment: i didnt create a new java for it

Comment: why don't you create another new java ? It would be more easy

Comment: I just created one, now pls tell me the code i need to put inside it :D. I also updated my github so my new java class will be on it

Comment: Have you updated your github? what have you changed?

Comment: I added the new class that you just asked for

Comment: Now if you have read my code, than can you pls tell me what i should put in my scoredisplay.java

Comment: sure, is my pleasure, but I didn't see your scoredisplay.java

Comment: hmm, do we have anyway of chatting cause i think you might be able to help me and i rly need help so, do you know any way we can chat?

Comment: https://github.com/muslimgilani/MultipleQandA here you go, this has the updated javaclass

Comment: I will write my answer. Give me a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getQuestionCount())
                updateQuestion();
                else
                    //Show next screen
                setContentView(R.layout.scoredisplay);
```

to

```
 if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getQuestionCount())
                updateQuestion();
 else
      {
           Intent intent =  new Intent(QuizActivity.this,ScoreDisplay.class);
           intent.putExtra("score",mScore);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
```

Create a new jave called ScoreDisplay, and receive the `mScore` value from QuizActivity to ScoreDisplay by using this

```
int score;

score= getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
```

Finally display the score to your `textView`.

```
textview.setText(score+"");
```

**ScoreDisplay.java**

```
public class ScoreDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

      TextView myScore;
       int score;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.scoredisplay);
            score= getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
            myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.endingScore);

            myScore.setText(score+"");
           }
    }
```

Add below code to your mainfest to solve crash problem.

```
<activity android:name=".ScoreDisplay"></activity>
```

**AndroidMainfest FullCode**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mgilani.co.multipleqa">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".QuizActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScoreDisplay"></activity>  //new line 
    </application>

</manifest>
```